# Ocaml multi-line function in REPL

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to write a multi-line function to use in an OCaml REPL. I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765234/write-a-multiline-function-in-ocaml), but the syntax suggested doesn't seem to work when using it in a REPL.

To use a contrived example, I can't get the following to compile:

```
let theFun: int -> int = fun x ->
    let foo = x;
    foo;;
```

When I enter it without the ";;" in this [online REPL](https://try.ocamlpro.com/), they get added in anyway and it gives me a syntax error. When I use a REPL on my local machine, the input won't get evaluated unless I include the ";;", and that gives me a syntax error as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is incorrect, a proper way to do it will be

```
let theFun: int -> int = fun x ->
    let foo = x in
    foo;;
```